# Cómo solucionar el error "== should be ==="?

Tags: angular

Component.ts

```js
  recomendedDocs: GuidelineRSC[] = [];
  selectedArray: GuidelineRSC[] = [];
  selectedData: GuidelineRSC[] = [];
```

```js
    onCheckboxChange(e) {
        const docsArray: FormArray = this.form.get('docsArray') as FormArray;

        if (e.target.checked) {
          docsArray.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
          // en la siguiente linea me salta el should be === en e.target.value == doc.id
          this.selectedData.push(this.recomendedDocs.find((doc) => e.target.value == doc.id));
        } else {
          let i = 0;
          docsArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
            // en la siguiente linea me salta el should be === en item.value == e.target.value
            if (item.value == e.target.value) {
              docsArray.removeAt(i);
              this.selectedData.splice(i, 1);
              return;
            }
            i++;
          });
        }
      }
```

Cuando ejecuto el lint me salta

> ERROR: routes/filepath... == should be ===

pero estos cambios no los puedo realizar porque la lógica de mi aplicación no funciona como deberia, muchas gracias por leer hasta acá, esperando me puedan colaborar con la solución del problema

Actualización: Me di cuenta que el valor que se le pasa al e.target.value es de tipo :any, y creeria que por eso me salta el error, no se como pasarle el tipo al parametro que se le pasa ("asumiendo que es de esa manera"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de los operadores de `===` y `==` como principal diferencia pudiera señalar que:

- El`===` se refiere a "exactamente igual", ambos valores son iguales y tienen el mismo tipo.
- El `==` por otro lado realiza una conversión implícita antes, de ser necesario, a fin de comparar ambos valores.

En tu caso como dices `e.target.value` tiene un tipo `any`.

Lo que pudieras hacer para librarte del error del linter, suponiendo que `doc.id` es de tipo string es lo siguiente de forma rápida:

```js
this.selectedData.push(this.recomendedDocs.find((doc) => (e.target.value as string) == doc.id));
```

Así mismo procederías en la otra línea dónde te salta el error.
En caso de que sea de otro tipo simplemente reemplazas `string` por ese otro tipo luego del `as`. Con esto debe ser suficiente para tu caso en particular pero en situaciones más generales lo más conveniente sería declarar una variable al inicio de tu función con el valor de `e.target.value` convertido, y luego usar esa variable en el resto de la función.

Siguiendo con este mismo caso en el que suponemos que es string:

```js
onCheckboxChange(e) {
  const value: string = e.target.value.toString();
  const docsArray: FormArray = this.form.get('docsArray') as FormArray;

  if (e.target.checked) {
    docsArray.push(new FormControl(value));
    // se usa value, la variable declarada al inicio
    this.selectedData.push(this.recomendedDocs.find((doc) => value === doc.id));
  } else {
    let i = 0;
    docsArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
      // se usa value, la variable declarada al inicio
      if (item.value === value) {
        docsArray.removeAt(i);
        this.selectedData.splice(i, 1);
        return;
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude. Si no es el caso, por favor comparte más detalles del problema en cuestión para que podamos brindarte una mejor solución.